# Xamarin: Binding a nested collection object to ListView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Please bear with me, I'm new to Xamarin

I have this object `Job` with a list of subobject `Process`

```
public class Job
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Process> Processes { get; set; }
    }

public class Process
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Procedure { get; set; }
    }
```

In the xaml page, I have a `SwipeView` that displays all the job `Title`s with an `Expander`, inside which I'm able to display the `Job.Date` for each `job`. But my issue is displaying a list of `Processes` inside a `ListView`.

ViewModel (redacted for brevity)

```
internal class MyJobsPageVM : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Job> MyJobs { get; }
        
        public MyJobsPageVM()
        {
            MyJobs = new ObservableCollection<CompJob>();
        }
        

        /* ... Code to load jobs with Rest Service into MyJobs ObservableCollection */
    }
```

XAML page (redacted for brevity)

```
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:MyJobsPageVM />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
                <CollectionView x:Name="JobsListSwipeCollectionView"
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding MyJobs}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <SwipeView>
                                <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                                    <SwipeItems Mode="Reveal" >
                                        <SwipeItem Text="Done"/>
                                    </SwipeItems>
                                </SwipeView.LeftItems>
                                <extensions:Expander>
                                    <extensions:Expander.Header>
                                         <Label>
                                                <Label.Text>
                                                    <MultiBinding>
                                                        <Binding Path="Title" />
                                                    </MultiBinding>
                                                </Label.Text>
                                         </Label>
                                    </extensions:Expander.Header>
                                    <StackLayout>
                                      <Label>
                                        <Label.Text>
                                            <MultiBinding>
                                                <Binding Path="Date" />
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </Label.Text>
                                      </Label>
<!-- This is where I am stuck -->    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding path=Processes}">
                                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <ViewCell>
                                                    <Label>
                                                        <Label.Text>
                                                            <MultiBinding>
                                                                <Binding Path="Description"/>
                                                            </MultiBinding>
                                                        </Label.Text>
                                                    </Label>
                                                </ViewCell>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                      </ListView>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </extensions:Expander>
                           </SwipeView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: generally speaking, nested ListViews are a bad idea.  However, what you have appears correct and should work in theory.

Comment: I don't know if case matters, but try `="{Binding Processes}"` or `="{Binding Path=Processes}"`. BTW, you didn't say **what goes wrong**. Syntax error, or empty list? If empty list, did you look in Output, to see if any relevant warning?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve There is no error or anything, the values just do not show up. I just realized that the problem is being caused by the `RefreshView` that I omitted in my post for keeping it simple. <RefreshView x:DataType="vm:MyJobsPageVM" Command="{Binding LoadJobRequestsCommand}"> I removed it, and all works well. Is it the `DataType` that is messing with the rest of the bindings?

Comment: If DataType causes a problem, you should see a warning in Output. In general, once you declare a datatype in xaml, any xaml **nested** "inside" that xaml element will need to have DataType declaration also, if a different datatype applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was being caused by the RefreshView that I omitted in my post for keeping it simple.  I removed it, and all works well.
I will try to find a better solution to reimplement the RefreshView functionality.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [BindableLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts) to display a collection of items without wrapping it in CollectionView.

You can refer to the following code:

```
   <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <form0530:MyJobsPageVM></form0530:MyJobsPageVM>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<StackLayout>
    <CollectionView x:Name="JobsListSwipeCollectionView"
                               ItemsSource="{Binding MyJobs}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}">

                            </Label>

                            <!-- add code here -->

                    <StackLayout  BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Processes}">
                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    </StackLayout>

                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I just realized that the problem is being caused by the `RefreshView` that I omitted in my post for keeping it simple. ```<RefreshView x:DataType="vm:MyJobsPageVM" Command="{Binding LoadJobRequestsCommand}">``` I removed it, and all works well. Is it the `DataType` that is messing with the rest of the bindings?